# No retina (best) display option

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, display

I have 2015 early macbook pro 13", but I can't seem to find the 2560x1600 resolution. The highest resolution I can set it on is 1680x1050. Default for display is only 1280x800.
What's the problem here? I'm using the newest Yosemite OS.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try 'Default for Display' as well as Scaled ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but the resolution is 1280x800.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will not show you the real panel resolution, only the scaled resolutions.

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-hack-to-run-native-resolution.html

Try this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hm, I tried holding option key while clicking "Scaled" in the display setting menu, but that didn't help :(